# iOS Swift - Get mime type from data

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using the PhotosPicker library to select either an image or a video and put it into data:

```
@State private var selectedImageData: Data? = nil
```

and I need to find out what exactly was selected.

All the answers I've found was about how to retrieve the meme type from a file using the path, but I don't get the file path using PhotosPicker.

I've found this somewhere:

```
extension Data {
    private static let mimeTypeSignatures: [UInt8 : String] = [
        0xFF : "image/jpeg",
        0x89 : "image/png",
        0x47 : "image/gif",
        0x49 : "image/tiff",
        0x4D : "image/tiff",
        0x25 : "application/pdf",
        0xD0 : "application/vnd",
        0x46 : "text/plain",
        ]

    var mimeType: String {
        var c: UInt8 = 0
        copyBytes(to: &c, count: 1)
        return Data.mimeTypeSignatures[c] ?? "application/octet-stream"
    }
}
```

and it works but it's incomplete, I also need mp4, mov and just as many as possible

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A quick research on Google with "mime types hexadecimal signatures" would give you [this](https://gist.github.com/Qti3e/6341245314bf3513abb080677cd1c93b) or [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures), for example...

---

**EDIT**

The array of signatures in your code reads the first byte of data of the file to determine its type.

- So first, according to the links I provided, is that to use just one byte might not be enough to determine the type of data (there can be multiple types with same first byte). You should first modify your code so a signature can be several bytes long.
- Then, you should use the links I provided, where, even if in different language, you get a list of first bytes linked to the related format, to fill your array of signatures and according types.

Here is the example code of what I am saying :

```swift
extension Data
{
    private static let mimeTypeSignatures: [([UInt8], String)] = [
        ([0x49, 0x49, 0x2A, 0x00], "image/tiff"),
        ([0x4D, 0x4D, 0x00, 0x2A], "image/tiff"),
        ([0x89, 0x50, 0x4E, 0x47, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x1A, 0x0A], "image/png"),
        //...
    ]

    var mimeType: String
    {
        let tenFirstBytes = Array(subdata(in: 0..<10))
        return Data.mimeTypeSignatures.filter
                   { signature in
                       tenFirstBytes.starts(with: signature.0)
                   }
                   .first?.1 ?? "application/octet-stream"
    }
}
```

It converts the 10 first bytes of the data to an array, then checks for each MIME type if the array starts with the MIME type bytes. (You will need to take more than ten bytes if MIME signatures are more than 10 bytes long).

Comment: I've found this too but how to use this gibberish? You think someone who learned how to use this would ask this question? xD

Comment: Yeah sorry, I thought it would be enough. I just edited my answer with more details.

Comment: Thats much better and it works, thanks!

Comment: why do you repeat "0x49, 0x49", "0x4D, 0x4D" and etc?

Comment: It is just the bytes that the file starts with. It so happens that a TIFF file starts with twice the same byte.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Signature re-using the code [here](https://lfcj.medium.com/read-image-format-of-data-in-swift-a5854e0079fc)

After copy-pasting the logic and adding the cases for tiff, vnd or text/plain, you will end up with this logic:

```
enum ImageFormat {
    case gif, jpg, png, vnd, tiff, unknown
}
if let data = someData {
    switch data.format() {
    case .jpg, .png, .gif:
        print ("Formats supported by Swift. Yihaaa")
    case .tiff:
        print ("Do some fancy decoding")
    case .pdf:
        print ("Read as a file")
    case .unknown:
        print ("Treat this data differently")
    }
}
```

If you do the comparison using a `String`, make sure to decode using `. isoLatin1`. If you compare the bytes using the keys inside your `mimeTypeSignatures`, then no need to. I only personally found it more readable to use Strings. It was helpful for decoding and to add tests.

Comment: But what about mp4, mov, webp, webm? Besides, there is no .format() on the data I'm receiving

Comment: @regina_fallangi provided .format() in the article linked at the top.  The signature for mp4 was also provided in the list at wikipedia.

Comment: @EduardUnruh, you create the `format()` inside a `extension Data`. There is an example in the article I posted above and you'd only need to extend it with the signature for mp4, mob and webm inside https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures

Comment: what is "format()"?

Comment: @Gargo, you create the format() inside a extension Data. There is an example in the article I posted above and you'd only need to extend it with the signature for mp4, mob and webm inside en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures